# Getting Error 503 trying to connect with Grouper with user and pass via python

Tags: python, authentication, http-proxy, api

I have an apache proxy server setup with following in my .htaccess file

```
#Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Header onsuccess unset Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding, x-api-token"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"


RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]

RewriteRule "^proxy/https/(.*)$" "https://$1" [P]
RewriteRule "^proxy/http/(.*)$" "http://$1" [P]
```

I am using python to connect using the below code but I get a 503 error. Any pointers appreciated

```
# Sample Basic Auth Url with login values as username and password
import requests
from base64 import b64encode
import json
import csv
import pythoncom
import win32com.adsi as adsi
import types
from pyad import aduser
import logging
import datetime
import os
import requests

url = "https://proxy.testserverenv.com/proxy/https/grouper.devenv.com/grouper-ws/servicesRest/v2_3_000/groups?wsLiteObjectType=WsRestFindGroupsLiteRequest&queryFilterType=FIND_BY_STEM_NAME&stemName=app:groupergroups"

user = "user"
passwd = "Pas$worD"

#debugging print statement 2/4
print("URL set")

# Make a request to the endpoint using the correct auth values
auth_values = (user, passwd)
response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_values)
```

Was trying to translate to Basic Auth to Header auth using

https://github.com/Internet2/grouper/blob/master/grouper-ws/grouper-ws/doc/samples/getGroups/WsSampleGetGroupsAdminsRestLite_admins_http_json.txt